# Which minyanim light Chanuka candles?

Tags: tefilla, chanuka, synagogue, maariv

In addition to the lighting at home, Chanuka candles are lit in shul to publicize the miracle, with the brachot (O"C 671:7).

Which minyanim do this?  All maariv minyanim in the shul(*)?  Just a shkiya mincha/maariv?  Just the earliest maariv in the shul?  Just the "main" maariv, whichever one that is?

Does a plag mincha/maariv minyan light?  (Most relevant in the southern hemisphere.)

(*) I'm assuming here that they all take place during a time when you can light candles.  A 3AM maariv would be excluded in most places, but I've never seen one.

Comment: Note that the mechaber (672:1) says that one can light *all night* if necessary so the 3 AM ma'ariv would not necessarily be excluded.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78542

Answer (score 4):

From [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Lighting_in_Shul#When_should_one_light_Chanukah_candles_in_the_Shul.3F):

The congregation should light Chanukah Candles **between Mincha and Mariv** even if it means lighting at sunset (Shekiyah) because the congregation would leave right after Mariv and there wouldn’t be Pirsume Nisa for the candles.

If a Shul has a few minyanim for Maariv, **the Menorah should remain lit from before the first minyan until after the last minyan¹**

---

1.Rav Chaim Kanievsky quoted in Sefer Yimei Hallel ViHodaah page 299 footnote 53. He adds that **if the Menorah burned out, or if the last minyan is much later than the first minyan, it should indeed be lit again before the last minyan with the berachot. Rabbi Eli Mansour writes that if the menorah burnt out it should be lit again but without a beracha.** see also Sh"t Yabea Omer 7:57 on the minhag of the Musayof Shul.

Comment: If it's remaining lit, someone should stay in the shul with it.  Otherwise it's dangerous.  A yahrtzeit candle is sturdy and you can put it in a sink, but not a menorah.

Comment: @Heshy definitely a good point. I remember hearing that there are opinions that one may extinguish the candles after 30 minutes if there's no one to watch them, but i don't have a source. Btw, is there any part of the question that i didn't address that you'd like me to add to my answer?

Comment: I think you covered everything but plag.  Maybe someone in Australia would know.

Answer (score 1):

In Moadei Yeshurun pg.17:5 writes that the menorah should be lit after mincha and on erev shabbas before mincha.

Rav Moshe(footnote 272) held that if there were two mincha minyanim then the bigger minyan should do the lighting because it is a bigger pirsumei nissa . I remember in a shiur from Rav Shmuel Fuerst that if there are multiple mincha minyanim then the first one lights with a bracha and the rest light without.

Rav Moshe(footnote 273) held that if there wasn't a mincha minyan prior and just is a maariv minyan the menorah is not to be lit because the takana was made only for after mincha before maariv.

There is a minhag to light by shachris without a bracha (footnote 274).